# Get return value from a function that relies on an asynchronous task

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, return, mvp

I'm doing a REST API call with Ion in order to log in a user. In order to do that, I'm getting the accessToken that Ion returns me (and this comes asynchronously). Initially, I was doing everything in the activity and inside the callback (I was getting the accessToken and then starting a new activity intent while sending this token to the next activity). It was working fine like that.
Now, I'm refactoring my project to an MVP architecture, so I've split the Ion network call to a different class (in the model layer level of MVP). However, I have a problem. It always returns me null and I suspect it's because the function returns before Ion finishes its async task. Any idea?

Here is the function that I want to get the loginSession from:

```
override fun userAuth(username: String,
                      password: String,
                      context: Context): LoginSession? {

    var loginSession: LoginSession? = null

    Ion.with(context)
            .load("https://myURL")
            .setBodyParameter("UserName", username)
            .setBodyParameter("Password", password)
            .asString()
            .setCallback { e, result ->
                try {
                    val json = JSONObject(result)
                    val expiresIn = json.getInt("expires_in")
                    val tokenType = json.getString("token_type")
                    val refreshToken = json.getString("refresh_token")
                    val accessToken = json.getString("access_token")
                    loginSession = LoginSession(expiresIn, tokenType, refreshToken, accessToken)

                } catch (jsonException: JSONException) {
                    jsonException.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
    return loginSession
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: ion have support for kotlin coroutines. Read [this](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/blob/master/AndroidAsync-Kotlin/README.md)

Comment: no problem @GP2Dev, be sure to upvote my question and answer if it helped you out, for others in future

Answer (score 0):

creates an interface, make the class where you wanna callback implements it.once you are done with the network call inside your model.
Use the method of that interface to get a callback in your activity/fragment.

You must have a reference of that interface in your model which must have been initialized with your activity/fragment object before your network calls start to process.

Note:- Your network call must be in Presenter in MVP and not in model.Retrofit already does all this more easily what i explained.You may use Retrofit instead of Ion.